# How to show error message under EditText in TextLayoutInput in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-edittext

For example I have a TextLayoutInput that allows user to put in password or email address\n

When the input type is not correct, i need the error message show up underneath the input line, like the design in here:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors

The xml code for TextLayoutInput is like this:

```
<TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>

    </TextInputLayout>
```

How do i achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: read the doc. there is a `setError` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. Read the section about **Floating labels for editing text** in [Android Design Support Library Documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). There it says:

> In addition to showing hints, you can also display an error message
>   below the EditText by calling setError().

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `TextView` under `EditText` and use `.setText("your error message")` to change it when an error occurs.